# Links overlap in post menu from flag queue

Tags: bug, design

The links under a question (the `div.post-menu` contents) in the flag queue overlap when it wraps to two lines.  You only really see it with the roll states, but I have had some accidental clicks as a result.

Comment: Can you please post the screenshot

Comment: @Bala Sadly, no.  Forgot to take one when it was happening...